How do I show a wifi signal strength meter in a cell of a datagridview? In C#
I have a list of different IOT, in a datagridview, in C#, that I would like to show WIFI signal strength for each on each row. This is for my own personal use.
I have found a 'Signal Strength Control in C#' by Ron Beyer, but it is not for use in a cell of a datagridview. What I have read is that I need to create my own custom datagridviewcolumn, cell and some other things. But I'm not sure quite how to put the two together.
Any help in this area would be great. Or how to do another way is ok too.

I added the winforms tag to make the UI framework clear

Your basic question seems to be how to draw a custom control (in this case to represent WiFi strength) in a DataGridViewCell. This is a possible duplicate of at least one other question. (Check out this answer that includes a demo you can clone.

Customizing the Windows Forms DataGridView Control -> Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells

Thank you very much. I just peaked at demo and I think it will answer all my questions. I off to investigate further

It would be the easiest to use DataGridImageCell and put images into your datasource.

Yes thank you, I see how that would be the easiest way to do this. I was thinking along the lines of learning how to implement a custom column so I might do it again with other needs in the future. A learning event.

I assume that you don't want to show one WIFI strength measurement in your datagridview but a sequence of similar measurements. For instance, measurements of several WIFI sources, or maybe the measurement during time.
Anyway, you want to show in your DataGridView a sequence of similar objects that have at least one property WifiSignalStrength, something like this:
class WifiMeasurement
{
    public string Ssid {get; set;}
    public DateTime Time {get; set;}
    public double Strength {get; set;}
    ... // other measurements
}

This will enable you to show the Measurements of several WIFI sources over time. If you only have one WIFI source, you won't need the SsId. If, on the other hand you don't want to show the strength over time, don't use Time.
Now, somehow you have a method that measures the WIFI strength, and saves the results in a sequence. How you do this, is out of scope of this question.
IEnumerable<WifiMeasurement> GetWifiMeasurements() {...}

Using Visual Studio Designer, you have added a DataGridView to your form, and added columns to your DataGridView. The DataGridView will show (several properties of) the sequence of WifiMeasurements.
In the constructor of your form, you define which column should show which property of WifiMeasurement:
public MyForm() : Form()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // define which column shows which property:
    this.columnSsid.DataPropertyName = nameof(WifiMeasurement.Ssid);
    this.columnTime.DataPropertyName = nameof(WifiMeasurement.Time);
    this.columnStrength.DataPropertyName = nameof(WifiMeasurement.Strength);
}

You can also do this in Visual Studio Designer, but this won't use nameof, but strings. If later you decide to change the name of the properties, but forget to change the strings, you won't see this until run time. Using nameof will let the complain if you forgot to change the code.
Now showing your measurements in the DataGridView is done in one statement:
this.dgvWifiMeasurements.DataSource = new List<WifiMeasurement>(this.GetWifiMeasurements);

Although this will show the measurements, the changes made by the operator (Add / Remove / Change) are not reflected. If the code needs to change (some) shown data, a new list must be loaded. This is because List<T> doesn't have methods to notify about changes.
If you want to be able to Add / Remove / Edit single rows of the DataGridView, you need a BindingList:
BindingList<WifiMeasurement> DisplayedWifiMeasurements
{
    get => (BindingList<WifiMeasurement> this.dgvWifiMeasurements.DataSource;
    set => this.dgvWifiMeasurements.DataSource = value;
}

Displaying your data is done in a similar way:
void ShowWifiMeasurements()
{
    this.DisplayedWifiMeasurements = new BindingList<WifiMeasurement>(
        new List<WifiMeasurement>(this.GetWifiMeasurements));
}

But now you have the advantage that the operator can edit the shown data. After making changes, he can click a button Apply Now:
void ButtonApplyNow_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    ICollection<WifiMeasurement> editedWifiMeasurements = this.DisplayedWifiMeasurements;

    // process the edited Wifi measurements: which rows are added / remove / changed
    // and act accordingly
    this.ProcessEditedWifiMeasurement(editedWifiMeasurements);
}

Some handy methods
Accessing  the current WifiMeasurements, or the selected Wifi Measurements, can be done in one line:
WifiMeasurement CurrentWifiMeasurement =>
    (WifiMeasurement) this.dgvWifiMeasurements.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;

IEnumerable<WifiMeasurement> SelectedWifiMeasurements =>
    this.dgvWifiMeasurements.SelectedRows
                            .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                            .Select(row => row.DataBoundItem)
                            .Cast<WifiMeasurement;

Usage:
WifiMeasurement currentWifiMeasurement = this.CurrentWifiMeasurement;

List<SelectedWifiMeasurement> selectedWifiMeasurements = this.SelectedWifiMeasurements.ToList();

Conclusion
To show properties of your class as columns in the DataGridView, use DataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName. Use nameof(...) to make sure that the properties exist.
To show your IEnumerable<WifiMeasurement> as a sequence of rows of WifiMeasurements in your DataGridView, use DataGridView.DataSource.
For easy access of edited cells, create a property DisplayedWifiMeasurements.
Use a BindingList for easy access of edited items
